# how to map the prop's property into Vue's attributes

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

there are many attribute I want to set in my component, but the first code is so bloated, I wonder if there is a better solution

```
<li class="ui-draggable-handle"
   v-for="(item, index) in deviceList" 
   :key="index"  
   :appid="item.subjectId" 
   :apptype="item.appType" 
   :model="item.subjectModel" 
   :shortModel="item.shortModel" 
   :appname="item.subjectName" 
   :state="item.state">
```

```
<my-li class="ui-draggable-handle"
   :mapping="{
      'appid': 'subjectId',
      'apptype': 'appType',
      'model': 'subjectModel',
      'shortModel': 'shortModel',
      'appname': 'subjectName',
      'state': 'state',
   }">
```

so how can I map the mapping in 's attributes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`v-bind`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) can take an object to bind multiple attributes/props at once. The directive's value could be an object literal:

```html
<li
   v-for="(item, index) in deviceList"
   v-bind="{
      'appid': item.subjectId,
      'apptype': item.appType,
      'model': item.subjectModel,
      'shortModel': item.shortModel,
      'appname': item.subjectName,
      'state': item.state,
   }">
```

...or an object variable, where only applicable keys are mapped (non-existing attributes/props are ignored):

```html
<li
   v-for="(item, index) in deviceList" 
   v-bind="item">
```

Answer (score 1):

First of, you can pass properties of an object as component props by binding the entire object, like it's described in [the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-the-Properties-of-an-Object):

```
<my-li v-bind="item" class="ui-draggable-handle">
```

Since your component's props do not correspond to the properties of your item object you could pass them like ***tony19*** has suggested in his answer. Though if you want to have your template look cleaner you could use a computed property instead of your original deviceList. like this:

```
computed: {
  deviceListMapped() {
    return this.deviceList.map(item => ({appid: item.subjectId, apptype: item.appType, model: item.subjectModel, shortModel: item.shortModel, appname: item.subjectName, state: item.state}))
  },
}
```

Then in your template your iterate through the deviceListMapped and v-bind its' items like this:

```
<my-li 
  v-for="(item, i) in deviceListMapped"
  :key="i"
  v-bind="item" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use computed properties like that

```
<my-li class="ui-draggable-handle"
   :mapping="mappingObject">
```

Computed object sets all the properties like that

```
computed: {
    mappingObject() {
      'appid': 'subjectId',
      'apptype': 'appType',
      'model': 'subjectModel',
      'shortModel': 'shortModel',
      'appname': 'subjectName',
      'state': 'state',
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just bind the whole item object in your iteration

```
<my-li class="ui-draggable-handle"
  v-for="(item, index) in deviceList" 
  :key="index"  
  :item="item">
</my-li>
```

Then you're can access the properties of the item inside the component like this

```
{{ item.subjectId }}
```